# What is `NSLocalizedFailureErrorKey` for?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, macos, nserror

Among the well-documented strings `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey`, `NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey`, `NSLocalizedRecoveryOptionsErrorKey`, and `NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey` there is also `NSLocalizedFailureErrorKey`, which lacks any kind of description in documentation. What is it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the header:

> ```
> FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSErrorUserInfoKey const NSLocalizedFailureErrorKey API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.13), ios(11.0), watchos(4.0), tvos(11.0));
> // NSString
> ```

> A complete sentence (or more) describing what failed.  Setting a value for this key in userInfo dictionary of errors received from framework APIs is a good way to customize and fine tune the localizedDescription of an NSError.

> As an example, for Foundation error code NSFileWriteOutOfSpaceError, setting the value of this key to "The image library could not be saved." will allow the localizedDescription of the error to come out as "The image library could not be saved. The volume Macintosh HD is out of space." rather than the default (say) “You can't save the file ImgDatabaseV2 because the volume Macintosh HD is out of space."

Answer (score 0):

Let me quote the documentation of `-localizedDescription` from `NSError.h` (I only applied some layouting and styling to it):

> The primary user-presentable message for the error, for
> instance for  `NSFileReadNoPermissionError`:
>
> *The file "File Name" couldn't be opened 
>
> because you don't have permission to view it.*
>
> This message should ideally indicate what failed and why it failed.
>
> This value either comes from
>
> - `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey`, or
> - `NSLocalizedFailureErrorKey` + `NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey`, or
> - `NSLocalizedFailureErrorKey`.
>
> The steps this takes to construct the description include:
>
> 1. Look for `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey` in `userInfo`,
>    use value as-is if present.
> 2. Look for `NSLocalizedFailureErrorKey` in `userInfo`. If present, use,
>    combining with value for `NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey` if available.
> 3. Fetch `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey` from `userInfoValueProvider`,
>    use value as-is if present.
> 4. Fetch `NSLocalizedFailureErrorKey` from `userInfoValueProvider`. If
>    present, use, combining with value for `NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey`
>    if available.
> 5. Look for `NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey` in `userInfo` or from
>    `userInfoValueProvider`; combine with generic "Operation failed" message.
> 6. Last resort localized but barely-presentable string manufactured from
>    domain and code. The result is never nil.